LCE marco sandri package
I'm using Mathematica 14 and trying to use professor marco sandri package to compute the Lyapunov exponents
https://www.msandri.it/soft.html
i download to my device the package with the red circle

but now I'm having a problem how to load a package to Mathematica, I already tried many ways that i found on the internet, but nothing is working.
can anyone help me with the steps to load the package to Mathematica please and thank you.

Previous question, now deleted: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/305767/package-help-base-directory

yes, i know, but i didn't get any answer that could help me, so i hope if anyone could help me with my problem

Well, just beware that in the past, the site does not appreciate people re-posting questions that don't get answered.

With less information than your previous version, I don't think anyone can do better than tell you to use Get[] on the .m file you downloaded. There are a couple tools built into M for locating files, such as FileNameSetter[Dynamic[pathname]], which gives me a dialog for clicking around my (Mac) file system. Needs[] probably won't work without bringing the package up to date, for reasons I mentioned before. I mention this in case someone recommends Needs[], which works well with packages that conform to standard package structure.

It should be something like Get["C:\home\lce.m"], but with the right pathname. (Windows uses \ not / to separate folder/directory names, right?)

as i can see in the link the lce.m is matlab code so is it ok ?

The lce.m file I obtained is in Mathematica code. Both Matlab and Mathematica (and Objective-C) use the .m filename extension. Some years ago, Mathematica changed to the .wl extension (for "Wolfram Language") but older files still have .m. Your operating system may be assuming .m means Matlab, but if you open the file with a text editor (in plain text/ascii mode), you can see whether the contents are Matlab code or Mathematica code. They don't look the same at all.

any idea how to convert it to Mathematica code please

Nope. As I said, it's not in Matlab code for me.

@MichaelE2 Mathematica running in Windows will take "c:/folder" or "c:\\folder"

The "A notebook with all the (updated) code used in the paper (for Mathematica 12)" just below the red circle seems to work fine.

@MelaGo Thanks for the help. I figured that a Windows user would know how to use Windows, and those who don't use Windows might not care. I think the OP is in the first clase, and I'm in the second. But since they seemed to struggle with finding the pathname to the file, I thought I'd give it a stab, since they hadn't received any other help. I'm sure they appreciate your advice.

yes, i appreciate all the help, for me since i don't have the experience on theses thing so that i can't join the discussion.

@A.Kato yes i just downloaded it and it's working but when i changed the original system to my system I'm having that error (too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision 
may be lost.)

I think you'd better ask question about how to avoid such errors, not about the installation of the old package. I'm not a specialist in dynamical system, so I cannot help you, though.
